# Paypal expresscheckout ErrorCode=7&Desc=Field format error: 10471-ReturnRUL is invalid

Tags: c#, paypal

I use PayPal `ExpressCheckout` in `asp.net C#` and got error:

> ErrorCode=7&Desc=Field format error: 10471-ReturnRUL is invalid.

when I debug my code

```
string returnURL = "http://www.mycompany.com/paypalConfirm.aspx";
.....
string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
string pStresponsenvp = HttpCall(pStrrequestforNvp, uid.ToString());

NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec(); 
decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
```

`returnURL` in `pStrrequestforNvp` showed `RETURNURL=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mycompany.com%2fpaypalConfirm.aspx`, it looked normal to me.

Can anyone help me find out why I got `10471` error?

Here is my whole request code:
    string host = "www.paypal.com";

```
string returnURL = "https://www.mycompany.com/paypalconfirm.aspx";
string cancelURL = "https://www.mycompany.com/paypalconfirm.aspx";

NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
encoder["METHOD"] = "SetExpressCheckout";
encoder["RETURNURL"] = returnURL;
encoder["CANCELURL"] = cancelURL;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT"] = amt;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION"] = "Sale";
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE"]  = "USD";
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME"]       = shipToName;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET"]     = shipToStreet;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2"]    = shipToStreet2;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY"]       = shipToCity;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE"]      = shipToState;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP"]        = shipToZip;
encoder["PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE"]= shipToCountryCode;

string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
string pStresponsenvp = HttpCall(pStrrequestforNvp,"");

NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
```

HttpCall return error code.

Comment: according to some forums this might be a problem over express (pro works as expected...) you may consider the pro version until paypal fix the express version

Comment: No, this is not a problem with Express Checkout.  Try removing the URL encoding and see if that helps.  If not, post a sample of your full raw request so I can take a peak.

Comment: Thanks for reply Andrew, but how to removing the URL encoding?

Comment: @AndrewAngell You save my day, removing the URL encoding works.